# DB path for Neo4j

Tags: java, maven, neo4j

I've created a Maven project, in which I created the class defined in this link :

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/1.9.5/community/embedded-examples/src/main/java/org/neo4j/examples/EmbeddedNeo4j.java

But I don't know how I can replace the value of the variable DB_PATH

```
 public class EmbeddedNeo4j

  {

   private static final String DB_PATH = "target/neo4j-hello-db";

   String greeting;

   // START SNIPPET: vars
   GraphDatabaseService graphDb;
   Node firstNode;
   Node secondNode;
   Relationship relationship;
// END SNIPPET: vars

// other instructions... and methods
 }
```

I have installed the Neo4j's .exe version and I can see the database in the browser going to: http://localhost:7474/browser/

My database location is this:

```
C:\Users\harun\Documents\Neo4j\default.graphdb
```

And on my code I'm writing :

```
private String DB_PATH = "Users\\harun\\Documents\\Neo4j\\default.graphdb";
```

The installation folder is:

```
C:\Program Files\Neo4j CE 2.3.3
```

And still doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: 'And still doesn't work.' Some more verbose information on what actually doesn't work would be helpful.

Comment: It doesn't show any error message. But when I check the DB it's void. In my main function I just call the method createDb() and shutDown()